# Can I change the font color of my Google Now card?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, samsung-galaxy-s-4, google-now

So in the From and Arriving on my Google now time cards, the values I put in are white. Which makes them unreadable.

Is there some way that I can change the text or card color so it is actually visible?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue, but it was fixed with the most recent Google Search update (I'm currently on version: 5.1.17.19.arm)

Comment: It must have updated yesterday on my phone, it is now looking good. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Try to uninstall updates of Google Search, and see if it works.

Comment: If you mean the "Google App", I can't. When I go into the App info of it, the Uninstall Updates is grayed out.